Having different coeffient values under the same variable name in modelsummary
I have a specific table format for my modelsummary in mind.
It is probably best to give an example and then describe what I want to change.
Some sample table:
reg1 <- lm(mpg ~  wt + qsec, data = mtcars)

mtcars2 <- mtcars*2

reg2 <- lm(mpg~ wt + qsec, data = mtcars2)

reglist <- list(A = reg1, B = reg2)

reglist2 <- list(A = reg1,B =  reg2)

msummar <- modelsummary(c(reglist, reglist2),
  stars = TRUE,
  statistic = NULL,
  shape =   term  + model ~ model,
  gof_map = c("adj.r.squared"),
  notes = list("Std. Errors in parentheses"),
  output = "gt")

Which gives this table

I want to modify this table so the columns only have one A and B each. The differentiation then happens on each row, where I have numbers (for each regression) under each variable "wt" and "qsec". For example: The Column A has two values (1) and (2) for the intercept and each variable.
The closest form I could find in the vignette for modelsummay is the grouping of parameters in a, for example, multinomial model. The example from the vignette is the following:
dat_multinom <- mtcars
dat_multinom$cyl <- sprintf("Cyl: %s", dat_multinom$cyl)

dat_multinom$cyl

mod <- list(
    nnet::multinom(cyl ~ mpg, data = dat_multinom, trace = FALSE),
    nnet::multinom(cyl ~ mpg + drat, data = dat_multinom, trace = FALSE))
  
get_estimates(mod[[1]])

modelsummary(mod, shape = model + term ~ response,
  output = "gt")

which gives:

The problem is, that I have lm models without grouping. As I understand it modelsummary uses get_estimates() to get its values. The resulting dataframe has a column called group, but I cannot give modelsummary the dataframe directly, as it expects some model class and not a df. Is there a way to "artificially" group the models to get the described format? Or any other way to archive this grouping of coefficients under each ind. variable?

I don't understand exactly what you need, and you don't supply a replicable example. That said, I believe you might be able to achieve what you want by using the shape argument. See this page for lots of details and examples on how to use shape: https://modelsummary.com/vignettes/modelsummary.html#shape

@Vincent I have added a lot more detail to the question, I hope it is clearer now. Is this edit fine or should I just ask a new question?

I'm traveling so I can't give you a more detailed answer, but you absolutely supply raw DFs to modelsummary, via the modelsummary_list construct. See: https://modelsummary.com/vignettes/modelsummary_extension.html#unsupported-models-modelsummary_list
